# Altium Draftsman Error: Layer Stack Legend

Tags: altium

I'm having an issue on Altium Draftsman where I can't insert the Layer Stack Legend from the Layer Stack on the PCB. I'm getting the following error when I try to insert the stack into the template. I just wanted to know if anyone had any potential solutions to this.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Altium forum?  They will also need to know which version of AD you are running.

Comment: I haven't yet. That was going to be my next move, but I'll go ahead and do it.

Comment: Cool, you are virtually certain to get an answer there.  Wouldn't hurt to post that answer here though in case someone else is looking.